# How do I set uget as a startup application

Tags: startup, startup-applications, uget

I want to make uget as a startup application in ubuntu. I am unable to understand how to add uget to startup application preferences as I cannot find its command. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command to run `uGet` is:

```
uget-gtk
```

To find the command to run a (globally installed) application, simply look into its `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`, and look for the *first line*, starting with `Exec=`.

In this case, the file is `/usr/share/applications/uget-gtk.desktop`. To open the file with `gedit`, drag it over an opened `gedit` window.

*Alternatively*
to find the (complete) command, you can make an "educated guess" on what the command should start with, in this case, typing:

`uget` + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

will complete the command into:

`uget-gtk`

#### Adding it to Startup Applications

This part you probably already know, but to be complete:
Open Dash > Startup Applications, click on the "Add" button, add the command `uget-gtk`

Comment: Hi @ArpanBiswas, did you manage?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Linux mint 19.1 Cinnamon, you can easily add uGet as Startup Application. Just search in the menu.